# iPhone Programming setNeedsDisplay not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Implemented my own drawRect method and I'm trying to redraw the shape from a Controller class and I can't figure out how to correctly implement setNeedsDisplay to redraw the UIView.  Please help!!

I know the code is ugly, but here is the custom method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
// Drawing code
NSArray *kyle = [self pointsForPolygonInRect:rect numberOfSides:[pshape numberOfSides]];
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

int counter = [kyle count];
NSLog(@"counter: %d",counter);
int i = 0;
BOOL first = YES;

NSValue *kylevalue;
CGPoint thePoint;
for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    kylevalue = [kyle objectAtIndex:i];
    thePoint = [kylevalue CGPointValue];
    if (first) { //start.
        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, thePoint.x, thePoint.y+5.0);
        first = NO;
    } else { //do the rest
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c,  thePoint.x, thePoint.y+5.0);
    }
}
CGContextClosePath(c); //solid color
CGContextDrawPath(c, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

}

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I'm trying to refresh the view from another class and when I call:

    [pview setNeedsDisplay];

Nothing happens.  It doesn't error when I run it, but it doesn't respond either.

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar problems with redrawing not working as I expected either. It seems as though setNeedsDisplay does not force children to redraw, for those you need to call their setNeedsDisplay method.

For my needs I wrote a category to redraw the entire screen by calling setNeedsDisplay on every single view. This can of course easily be modified to start from a specific view as opposed to all windows.

```
@implementation UIApplication (Extensions)

+ (void) redrawScreen {
 NSMutableSet* todo = [NSMutableSet set];
 NSMutableSet* done = [NSMutableSet set];
 [todo addObjectsFromArray:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]];

 while ([todo count] > 0) {
  UIView* view = [todo anyObject];
  [view setNeedsDisplay];

  [done addObject:view];
  [todo removeObject:view];

  if (view.subviews) {
   NSMutableSet* subviews = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:view.subviews];

   [subviews minusSet:done];
   [todo unionSet:subviews];
  }
 }
}

@end
```

Hope this is of help to someone

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question.  Calling -setNeedsDisplay on a view causes it to be redrawn via its -drawRect: method.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm trying to refresh the view from another class and when I call: [pview setNeedsDisplay]; Nothing happens. It doesn't error when I run it, but it doesn't respond either.  I put an NSLog message to display when it enters drawRect and it only enters once when the application launches.

Comment: You should check that pview is not nil, since messages sent to nil are silently ignored.

Answer (score 0):

just a few thoughts
1. have you verified that your method is getting called?
2. have you verified that your array of points is in fact populated with more than one point?
3. are the points actually in the viewable area of the frame?
4. I don't see you setting the stroke line width, color or fill colors.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes reason can be very simple: File's owner has no connection to UIView object. i.e. it's Outlet is not setup properly. 
Use IB, ctrl button and drag method :)

Answer (score 0):

If your plot has the drawRect method, look at your viewController, at the code where it connects to your plot. Is that hooked up properly? Is the little circle by the property hollow? or filled in. That little circle must be filled in if the property is connected properly. If it is hollow, bring up the story board.

Find the plot object in the story board. Control drag from the plot object in the story board over to the empty circle on the view controller. Now you've hooked up the outlet. Try running it again, and see if your drawRect is called now.