# User selected themes in iOS - Is a setNeedsDisplay possible on the entire UI?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, setneedsdisplay

I've added a user selected theme option to my app. Each relevant element (mostly UIViews) conditionally change their appearance dependent on the state of an NSUserDefaults BOOL.

This worked fine when I was setting the state using a #define followed by Build and Run. But, I need the UI to "refresh" when the user flips a switch.

In theory *I think* I need to cascade a setNeedsDisplay down from self.window. Is there a smart way to achieve this. I've tried working down through the subViews using @mattmook's solution in the link below but it doesn't go far enough and I'm not certain it's the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do.

[iPhone Programming setNeedsDisplay not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117229/iphone-programming-setneedsdisplay-not-working)

Can someone either confirm that this is the best method or suggest something simpler?

Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 2):

Make the interested views listen to a notification. When data change, send a notification and let all the views update themselves.

In general, it's better to have such functionality decentralized.

Comment: I agree.  You'll probably spend too much time iterating through UIViews that don't need to change if you try to navigate your entire view hierarchy.  This is a problem NSNotification is designed to solve.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you actually apply the color change. Did you subclass each UIView object that you are using to ensure that it fetches its color from whereever and changes it accoringly before drawing itself? Such as overwriting drawRect like this:

```
- (void) drawRect:... {

  if (somehowFetchTheUserDefaultsBoolValueHere) {
    self.tint = [UIColor redColor];  // details here may vary depedning on the actual superclass
  } else {
    self.tint = [UIColor greenColor];
  }

  [super drawRect:...];
}
```

(Just showing the principle. There are actually smarter ways of coding that.)

If you did that then `setNeedsDisplay` on the current view controller's `self.view` would do. (on the main thread if in doubt)

Alternative:
If you perform the tinting by any other means then you need to execute that code which tints all currently presented views. That is in most cases the view controller on top. For all other view controllers you could place the tinting code in their `viewWillAppear` method. Works fine. Did that myself just rechently.

However, subclassing all views could be more efficient as it means a once-off effort only, depending on the total size of your app. Plus it could be re-used in other apps.

Answer (score 0):

If I was going to make sure I hit setNeedsDisplay on each individual view (or call a commonly named method like drawRect or whatever a custom method like refresh view) then I'd do it recursively

```
-(UIView *)redrawView:(UIView *)theView
{
    if([[theView subviews] count] = 0)
    {
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
        return theView;
    }

    for(UIView *subview in theView.subviews)
    {
        UIView *result = [self redrawView:subview];
        if(result) return result;
    }
    return nil;
}
```